# AWS Lambda function returning wrong value from Database query

Tags: mysql, aws-lambda

I am working on AWS Lambda and writing a method to get data from SQL Database.

Here is my code:

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('Events:',event);
  let UserHierarchyGroupID = event['hierarchyGroupId'];
  let team = [];
  // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let sql = `SELECT date(Feedback.DateTime),Feedback.Score,UserHierarchy.Layer5
               FROM ctrData2.Feedback
               LEFT OUTER JOIN ctrData2.CallDetail ON CallDetail.ContactId = Feedback.FeedbackID
               LEFT OUTER JOIN ctrData2.UserTable ON UserTable.UserID = CallDetail.UserID
               LEFT OUTER JOIN ctrData2.UserHierarchy ON UserTable.UserID  = UserHierarchy.UserID
               WHERE UserTable.UserHierarchyGroupID=?`;
    let field = [UserHierarchyGroupID];
    connection.query(sql,field, function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      // console.log(result);
      connection.release();
    if(result.length>0){
           result.forEach((item)=>{
             team.push({
               "TeamName": item.Layer5,
               "DataTime": item.DataTime
               
             });
           });
           
      }else{
            callback(null,{
              status: 404,
              Body: "Not found"
            });
          }
      callback(null,team);
      // FomratObjects(result,(formattedResponse)=>{
      //   // console.log(formattedResponse);
      //   callback(formattedResponse);
      // });
    });
  });
};
```

**It only shows me TeamName not DateTime**

`(select date(Feedback.DateTime)` I am separating date here from from DateTime column because I only want date from that column.

Comment: Are u having some typo?
**"DataTime": item.DataTime**
Isn't that supposed to be **DateTime**

Comment: Your column name is **DateTime** right

Comment: yes my column name was DateTime but when i right a query and sperate date from DateTime coloum it becomes **Date(Feedback.DateTime)**

Comment: team.push({
               "TeamName": item.Layer5,
               "DataTime": item.DataTime
               
             });

Comment: I was more concerned about this part. Did you have a typo there?

Comment: I can see **item.DataTime**. Shouldnt that be **item.DateTime**

Comment: what do you mean by type? and if it shouldnt be **item.DateTime**.....what it should be then?

Comment: yes it should be item.DateTime right. I can see it as item.DataTime in your code.

Comment: hahaha thank man i don't know what was just happend i was stuck in this from yesterday :D

Comment: but its still not sowing with **SELECT date(Feedback.DateTime)** this things......if we update query with  **feedback.DateTime** then its working fine

Comment: Done, i just make an alias **(SELECT date(Feedback.DateTime) as datetime)** like this and show it like **"DateTime": item.datetime**.. Thanks for your time @nithin11 :)